# How to change image stanza request using Xmpp Android

Tags: android, xmpp

i have to pass stanza in my code like in this below format:

```
<message type="set" id="ANY_ID_NAME" from="919586082989@abc.com" to="919033301266@abc.com" chattype="singlechat"><data xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb" seq="1" sid="i781hf64">imgdata</data><timestamp>2017-06-16 17:08:37</timestamp><mediatype>image</mediatype></message>
```

how will i able to do because i am not getting the stanza request sending class not getting proper function from where did i edit code.

As in code i found this function from which stanza string generate :

```
private synchronized void sendPacket(final AbstractStanza packet) {
    if (stanzasSent == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        resetStreamId();
        disconnect(true);
        return;
    }
    synchronized (this.mStanzaQueue) {
        tagWriter.writeStanzaAsync(packet);
        if (packet instanceof AbstractAcknowledgeableStanza) {
            AbstractAcknowledgeableStanza stanza = (AbstractAcknowledgeableStanza) packet;
            ++stanzasSent;
            this.mStanzaQueue.append(stanzasSent, stanza);
            if (stanza instanceof MessagePacket && stanza.getId() != null && getFeatures().sm()) {
                if (Config.EXTENDED_SM_LOGGING) {
                    Log.d(Config.LOGTAG, account.getJid().toBareJid() + ": requesting ack for message stanza #" + stanzasSent);
                }
                tagWriter.writeStanzaAsync(new RequestPacket(this.smVersion));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2)   and also found this function in XmppConnection class . as is this is correct method which i found

```
private void sendStartStream() throws IOException {
    final Tag stream = Tag.start("stream:stream");
    stream.setAttribute("to", account.getServer().toString());
    stream.setAttribute("version", "1.0");
    stream.setAttribute("xml:lang", "en");
    stream.setAttribute("xmlns", "jabber:client");
    stream.setAttribute("xmlns:stream", "http://etherx.jabber.org/streams");
    tagWriter.writeTag(stream);
}
```

Please suggest me how did i change my image stanza request which i posted above.

Comment: hey can you try it once https://github.com/saveendhiman/XMPPSample_Studio

Comment: I am not using openfire. as i am using ejaberred. so its not helpful for me

Comment: You just need to change url nothing else

Comment: Openfire is just a server. You can use same ejaberred as well.

Comment: In your provide link, I got crashing issue when I try to login with my ejabbred user 
And I had checked https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OrL9mepFLQU this video and not seeing any option for image sharing.
Is image sharing is working in provide link?
Image sharing is working in my project but due to xmpp stanza difference It will not work with iOS device It is working with android to android app only So I want to change my stanza as per listed above So Please do need full for that